# PDOException: cache_clear_all()

Tags: drupal, pdo, drupal-7

I moved to a new server with my Drupal 7 site. However, I get the error:

> PDOException: cache_clear_all()
>   SQLSTATE[42S02: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Zadmin_akademi92anka.cache_metatag' doesn't exists:
>   TRUNCATE {cache_metatag} ; Array( ).

Comment: Did you move the Drupal database to the new site?

Answer (score 0):

It appears a table was lost in the move. Disabling the module metatag would be a quick fix. If you can't disable that module through the UI then you can do it my setting the status to 0 on the related row in the "system" table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Just ry to recreate the 'cache_metatag' table, it happend to me too, eventhough I just install a fresh Metatag module. It seems there is some process interupt or install failed when you enable this module, can be the connection or else where on the server side.

All cache table has the same structure, so you can copy the table structure for 'cache_metatag' table from another cache table.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is clearly written in the error message: a table doesn't exit.

Comment: So, why not ?What should I do ? Please help me.. I tried very hard.

Comment: I get this error in each operation. For example, cache cleaning, new member registration